# Totally new to Ubuntu. Need help with nVidia drivers

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics

I'm very new to Ubuntu.

After a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS x64, what are the steps I should take to install the nVidia graphics drivers?

I'm using a Gigabyte 980Ti G1 Gaming.

I've been going around and trying different ways. But every time after having installed a driver it forces my screen to a very small resolution.

So I just want to know the steps that you take to successfully install the drivers and getting them to work, in the hope that I can finally continue using Ubuntu for my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using very new GPU hardware, it is recommended to also use the latest stable drivers.

Install the latest stable **NVIDIA drivers supporting 980Ti** from the Proprietary GPU drivers PPA.

Open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352 
sudo reboot
```

Answer (score 0):

Run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-346
```

and reboot.